# How to send and receive newline character over sockets in a client server model?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client-server

I am trying to learn client server model in Linux and I have setup two C files namely server.c and client.c. These are the code snippets that I seem to have problems with.

server.c code snippet

```
char* message = "<query>\n";
write(client_socket_filedescriptor, message, sizeof(message));
```

client.c code snippet

```
char* message = "<query>\n";
read(socket_filedescriptor, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
printf("%s", buffer);
printf("\n\n");
printf("%s", message);
```

Now when I run my server and then when I run my client, I expect the printf statements to print the same strings that is `<query>\n`, but I keep getting different outputs for `buffer` and `message` variables.

The output looks a bit like this when I run client code.

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S94lx.png)

As you see, these two strings are different. I am trying to simulate a typical TCP handshake and I want to make sure that these two strings are same and then client will start writing or doing something with that server. But I am having this trivial problem. Could anyone tell my how to resolve it? I plan to use strcmp to compare buffer and message variables, but as it stands now, strcmp doesn't return 0 since these are different strings afterall.

Comment: `sizeof(message)` --> `strlen(message)+1`

Comment: So you mean that I should change `sizeof(message)` to `strlen(message)`? If so, I am getting an error as read call is only reading the first character.

Comment: Yes you need to change that - `sizeof(message)` gives the size of the pointer not what it points to. If you still get errors then obviously there are other bugs in your program. For example, it is a common error to assume that `read` will always receive the entire message. `read` must always be called in a loop with its return value checked to determine how many bytes were read. Provide a [mcve] if you want further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ignoring the count returned by `read()`. It can be -1, indicating an error, or zero, indicating end of stream, or a positive number, indicating how many bytes were received. You cannot assume that `read()` fills the buffer, or that a single `send()` or `write()` corresponds to a single `recv()` or `read()`.

In detail:

```
write(client_socket_filedescriptor, message, sizeof(message));
```

You are only sending four bytes, the size of the pointer. And you're ignoring the return value. It should be

```
int count = write(client_socket_filedescriptor, message, strlen(message));
if (count == -1)
    perror("write"); // or better

char* message = "<query>\n";

read(socket_filedescriptor, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

That should be

```
int count = read(socket_filedescriptor, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if (count == -1)
    perror("read"); // or better
else if (count == 0)
    ; // end of stream: the peer has disconnected: close the socket and stop reading
else
```

Back to your code:

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

That should be

```
printf("%.*s", count, buffer);
```

> I plan to use `strcmp()`

You should plan to use `strncmp()`, with `count` above as the length parameter. In any case you can't assume the input ends with a null unless you (a) ensure you send the null, which you aren't, and (b) write a read loop that stops when you've read it.

Comment: printf statements that you gave print both buffer and message variables as same, but when I remove your `.*` syntax along with count(only in the printf), I get the old output back again meaning that your code just formats the printf statements, but buffer and message never contain the same strings. Is there a way I can make sure that I read only `<query>\n` and not some extra weird characters?

Comment: @lufork You didn't receive any 'extra weird characters'. They were already there, and you printed them because your `printf()` call was incorrect. The `printf()` statement that I gave is correct, because it bounds what is output to what was actually received, i.e. `count` bytes. You should use the same upper bound when copying or otherwise processing this buffer, in whatever code you may have for that that wasn't posted, rather than assuming that `read()` filled the buffer, as I already said. I can only comment on code you actually posted.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks.